# Deactive LinkToPrevious At the Last Section of Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been asked to put 3 separate documents in 1 .docx file. The first document should have page numbers in X of Y format on the footer and the other 2 that follow should not have page numbers. I put in a section break immediately after the first document so that I could deactivate the Link to Previous option. However, I cannot seem to deactivate the Link to Previous option for the second section of the document using a macro. I can only deactivate the Link to Previous option for the first section or the entire document with a macro. I know I can do so manually but I don't want the user to have to do this. I've included code for 2 of the methods that I have tried, neither of which produced the desired result.

```
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
     ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
     ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
     ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter 
'As I understand it, these lines of code move the cursor to the footer. I got them from recording a macro.

Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = Not Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious 
'This is the line of code generated from recording a macro that deactivated the LinkToPrevious option,
'but when run as part of a macro, it turns off LinkToPrevious for the entire document despite there 
'being a section break on the page prior to where the cursor is when this line of code is executed

ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False 'I also tried this code.
'This turns off LinkToPrevious for the whole document; I only want it turned off for the 
'2nd section of the document
```

I want to turn off LinkToPrevious for only the last section of my document using the macro. Can this be done?

Comment: Your question shows you haven't even done even the the most basic research on headers and footers in word.   In the VBIde put your cursor on  .LinkToPrevious and press F1.

Comment: I've spent over 3 hours trying to find answers and get this to work myself. I looked at this webpage https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.headerfooter.linktoprevious, which I think is what you're referring to, but that has instructions on how to change headers for even and odd number pages, which is not what I'm looking to do. The fact that ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Footers() has only the arguments: wdHeaderFooterPrimary, wdHeaderFooterEvenPages and wdHeaderFooterOddPages makes me think this may not be possible

Sorry if I'm not asking great questions, I am a beginner in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim HdFt As HeaderFooter
With ActiveDocument.Sections.Last
  For Each HdFt In .Headers
    HdFt.LinkToPrevious = False
  Next
  For Each HdFt In .Footers
    HdFt.LinkToPrevious = False
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

For a comprehensive solution, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html. As you'll see from both the above and the code in that link, there is also no need to mess with:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Word has three types of header and three types of footer. `ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False` will turn off `LinkToPrevious` in the second section ***only***, but only for one of the three types of footer. If you don't know which are used in the document just loop through all three.

If you think the help text only gives "instructions on how to change headers for even and odd number pages", you're reading it wrong.

There is no such enum as "wdHeaderFooterOddPages".